# Unable to draw in Leaflet after update of a marker position using geolocation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm using Leaflet, Leaflet-draw and Cordova Geolocation. When the map is loaded (globe view) it is possible to draw correctly, when locate function is called mapcenter and marker position are update but become impossible to draw. Draw toolbar is visible and clickable but any tool selected doesn't work when I use it, I don't receive any error in logger, it seems that the draw editable layer "disappear"...

Link to Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6DH7o3HyPzbpCJs7szcn?p=preview

This is my code:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ui-leaflet','ngCordova'])
.controller("MapCtrl", [ "$scope", "leafletData", "$cordovaGeolocation", function($scope, leafletData, $cordovaGeolocation) {
  angular.extend($scope, {
    center: {
      lat: 51.505,
      lng: -0.09,
      zoom: 4
    },
    controls: {
      draw: {}
    },
    markers:{
      tracker: {
          lat: 51.505,
          lng: -0.09,
          message: "You're here!",
          focus: false,
          icon: {},
      }
    },
    layers: {
      baselayers: {
        bingAerial: {
          name: 'Bing Aerial',
          type: 'bing',
          key: 'Aj6XtE1Q1rIvehmjn2Rh1LR2qvMGZ-8vPS9Hn3jCeUiToM77JFnf-kFRzyMELDol',
          layerOptions: {
            type: 'Aerial'
          }
        }
      },

      overlays: {
        draw: {
          name: 'draw',
          type: 'group',
          visible: true,
          layerParams: {
            showOnSelector: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Cordova Geolocation
  $scope.locate = function(){
    console.log(leafletData);
    var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
    $cordovaGeolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
    .then(function (position) {
      $scope.center.lat = position.coords.latitude
      $scope.center.lng = position.coords.longitude
      $scope.center.zoom = 19
      $scope.markers.tracker.lat = position.coords.latitude
      $scope.markers.tracker.lng = position.coords.longitude
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });
    setInterval(function(){
      var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
      $cordovaGeolocation
      .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
      .then(function (position) {
        $scope.markers.tracker.lat = position.coords.latitude
        $scope.markers.tracker.lng = position.coords.longitude
      }, function(err) {
        // error
      });
    },5000)
  }
  // /Cordova Geolocation


  leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
    console.log(leafletData);
    leafletData.getLayers().then(function(baselayers) {
      var drawnItems = baselayers.overlays.draw;
      map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
        var layer = e.layer;
        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON()));
      });
    });
  });
}])
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ui-leaflet/dist/ui-leaflet.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/elesdoar/ui-leaflet-layers/master/dist/ui-leaflet-layers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/leaflet-plugins/layer/tile/Bing.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css" />

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
        <a class="button" ng-click ='locate();'>Locate</a>
      </ion-header-bar>


      <ion-content ng-controller ='MapCtrl'>
        <a class="button" ng-click ='locate();'>Locate</a>
        <leaflet lf-center="center" controls="controls" markers='markers' layers="layers" width="100%" height="400"></leaflet>
      </ion-content>

    </ion-pane>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Can you set up an example in Plunker?

Comment: What the periodical code in `setInverval` is supposed to do? I would recommend using `$interval` service instead, since you would be sure that the $digest cycle would run and your changes would be "visible" to angular.

Comment: I use setInterval to update the local position through geolocation every 5 seconds. Thank you for you suggestion to use $interval ;) the problem still remains..

Comment: @tasseKATT I've created a plunker to my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/6DH7o3HyPzbpCJs7szcn?p=preview

Comment: I will take a look in a while.

Comment: I don't even have to click the `Locate` button. Just clicking right of it once will make the control panel stop working. Can you confirm?

Comment: Found the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it stops working is because Ionic's own tap system doesn't play nicely with Leaflet's.

The following [Ionic documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/) has more information:

> In some cases, third-party libraries may also be working with touch
>   events which can interfere with the tap system. For example, mapping
>   libraries like Google or Leaflet Maps often implement a touch
>   detection system which conflicts with Ionic’s tap system.

Disable Ionic's tap system on the specific element to make it work:

```
<leaflet data-tap-disabled="true" ...
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/LlhpTGYHNMBUzNo1oSwF?p=preview